# Is paraconsistent logic used in other areas of mathematics other than discrete mathematics and in other areas such as physics and philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

Is paraconsistent logic used in other areas of mathematics other than discrete mathematics and in other areas such as physics and philosophy? I heard that paraconsistent logic is an area of discrete mathematics, but I am wondering if there are any other mathematical or non-mathematical applications for it.

Comment: Discrete mathemtics is a pretty wide area, but no, there is nothing specifically discrete about paraconsistent theories, they can just as well be "continuous", like analysis. For some applications see [SEP, Inconsistent Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/).